# Why is the letter 'm' not displaying correctly in the interface in Blender 2.82?

Tags: interface

Recently something happened in my Blender and I  noticed that **m** is not displayed properly. Can someone tell me reason for this? Only small **m** is not displayed properly, Capital **M** is displayed ok. Even when I rename something small **m** is displayed like show in below picture. What I did last was, I installed Hardop 0098 Add-On.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you add a larger screen shot? I can read the letters in that resolution.

Comment: @Leander I have added larger screenshot for your convenience

Comment: Sorry, it was a wrong setting on my end, the first image was fine.Have you tried another blender installation as a zip?

Comment: After updating to 2.83 Beta, it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try configure another font to check if something is broken on font side inside your computer. Here where you can do it:

[image]

You can also try:

1. install a brand new blender (on a different folder)
2. load the default configuration file

good luck